# Sum of number of divisor of number between a and b inclusive

Tags: algorithm, numbers

Let there be a function **g(x)=number of divisor of x**. Given two integers a and b we need to find->

**g(a)+g(a+1)....+g(b).**

I thought this step->

```
for every x from a to b

sum+=number of divisor of x(in sqrt(x) complexity)
```

but  its given **1<=a<=b<=2^31-1**

So to iterate between a and b can cost me a lot of time....for eg->if a=1 and b=2^31-1.

Is there a better way to do?

Comment: Are you given many `a` and `b` pairs or just one?

Comment: There can be many pairs in a test case!

Comment: You may learn more at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisor_function

Comment: @user2826957 what's |b-a|?

Comment: @ Akashdeep Saluja Its given b>=a...

Comment: @user2826957 I meant to say that Is there an upper limit on |b-a| ?

Comment: You'd probably be surprised how quickly modern computers can count to 2^32...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's some simple but reasonably efficient Python code that does the job.

```
import math

def T(n):
    "Return sum_{i=1}^n d(i), where d(i) is the number of divisors of i."
    f = int(math.floor(math.sqrt(n)))
    return 2 * sum(n // x for x in range(1, f+1)) - f**2

def count_divisors(a, b):
    "Return sum_{i=a}^b d(i), where d(i) is the number of divisors of i."
    return T(b) - T(a-1)
```

Explanation: it's enough to be able to compute the sum from `1` to `b`, then we can do two separate computations and subtract to get the sum from `a` to `b`.  Finding the sum of the divisor function from `1` to `b` amounts to computing [sequence A006218](http://oeis.org/A006218) from the online encyclopaedia of integer sequences.  That sequence is equivalent to the sum of `floor(n / d)` as `d` ranges over all integers from `1` to `n`.

And now *that* sequence can be thought of as the number of integer-valued points under the hyperbola `xy=n`.  We can use the symmetry of the hyperbola around the line `x = y`, and count the integer points with `x <= sqrt(n)` and those with `y <= sqrt(n)`.  That ends up double counting the points with both `x` and `y` less than `sqrt(n)`, so we subtract the square of `floor(sqrt(n))` to compensate.  All this is explained (briefly) in the introduction to [this paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/1206.3369).

Remarks:

- the algorithm has running time `O(sqrt(b))`, and constant space requirements.  Improvements in running time are possible at the expense of space; see the paper referred to above.
- for really large `n`, you'll want a proper integer square root rather than using `floor(math.sqrt(n))`, to avoid problems with floating-point inaccuracies.  That's not a problem with the sort of `n` that you're looking at.  With typical IEEE 754 floating-point and a correctly rounded square root operation, you're not going to run into trouble until `n` exceeds `2**52`.
- if `a` and `b` are *really* close, there may be more efficient solutions.

Comment: Very elegant answer with a couple of nice tricks that are well explained and fully understandable to people who have never heard of the divisor summatory function (`T`, A006218).  Plus a clean, concise and efficient code.  Good job!

Answer (score 1):

Because the desired result is the total number of divisors for all the numbers in a range, there's no need to count divisors of individual numbers in the range; instead, count the number of times 1 is a divisor, 2  is a divisor, etc.  This is an O(b) computation.

That is, add up `b-(a-1)`, `b/2 - (a-1)/2`,  `b/3 - (a-1)/3`, etc. .

In the python code shown below (which uses python operator // for integer division with truncation) divisors from 2 to about b/2 are counted using a `for` loop.  Note that divisors that are smaller than `b` but larger than `max(a, b/2)` occur once each and need not be counted in a loop.  The code uses the expression `b-max(a,(b+1)//2+1)+1` to count them.  Output is shown after the program.

When `k` different `a,b` sets are to be treated, it is possible to compute all the answers in time O(k+`bₘₐₓ`) where `bₘₐₓ` is the largest value of `b`.

Python code:

```
def countdivisors(a,b):
    mid = (b+1)//2+1
    count = b-a+1 +b-max(a,mid)+1 # Count for d=1 & d=n
    for d in xrange(2,mid):
        count += b//d - (a-1)//d
    return count
# Test it:
a=7
for b in range(a,a+16):
    print '{:3} {:3} : {:5}'.format(a, b, countdivisors(a,b))
```

Output:

```
  7   7 :     2
  7   8 :     6
  7   9 :     9
  7  10 :    13
  7  11 :    15
  7  12 :    21
  7  13 :    23
  7  14 :    27
  7  15 :    31
  7  16 :    36
  7  17 :    38
  7  18 :    44
  7  19 :    46
  7  20 :    52
  7  21 :    56
  7  22 :    60
```

Answer (score 0):

We can adapt this algorithm: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes
by adding 1 to all multiples instead of flagging them as "not prime"

it  will be o(n.ln(n)) with a=1 and b=n (i think)

algorithm for 1 to n:

```
g: array of n elements
for i starting with 2 to n
    if g[i]== 0
        for each multiple of i <n
            g[i] += 1
```

Comment: In the sieve method we skip some composite numbers like 12, but they may be are divisor of some numbers between a and b, and we should count them multiple time.

Comment: Yes, i didn't see that. It will work if test if g[i]==0 before looping on each multiple of i. We will only add 1 if i is prime.

Answer (score 0):

You can sieve for the count of divisors, then sum the counts:

```
function divCount(a,b)
    num := makeArray(1..b, 0)
    for i from 1 to b
        for j from i to b step i
            num[j] := num[j] + 1
    sum := 0
    for i from a to b
        sum := sum + num[i]
    return sum
```

This is similar to a Sieve of Eratosthenes, but instead of marking off the composites it counts each divisor for every number, including both primes and composites. If *b* is too large, you can perform the sieving in segments.

Comment: To save time, you can cap the inner loop at sqrt(b) and add 2 instead. If it equals the square root exactly you add just 1.

Comment: @Geobits I don't think you can. We're creating a sieve, not calculating all divisors of a number.

Comment: @Dukeling Well, you can do what I had in mind, I just said it completely wrong. See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19386157/752320) for what I actually meant.

Answer (score 0):

Another sieve-based answer, but with a better time complexity than the others. This one also handles segmentation easily, since it only sieves numbers `{a...b}` on each run. The function returns an `int[]` with the number of divisors for each number from `a` to `b`. Just sum them up to get the final answer.

If your inputs are larger, you can split it up and add the sums from each returned segment.

Java:

```
public static int[] getDivisorCount(int a, int b){
    int[] sieve = new int[b - a + 1];
    double max = Math.ceil(Math.sqrt(b));
    for(int i = 1; i <= max; i++){
        int j = (a / i) * i;
        if(j < a)
            j += i;
        for( ; j <= b; j += i){
            double root = Math.sqrt(j);
            if(i < root){
                sieve[j - a] += 2;
            }else if(i == root){
                sieve[j - a]++;
            }
        }
    }
    return sieve;
}
```

The outer loop runs `sqrt(b)` times. The inner loop runs something like `log(b-a)` times, so unless I'm mistaken, the final complexity should be something like `O(sqrt(b) * log(b))`, since worst case is `a=1`. Feel free to correct me on that.

If you're handling large inputs and you have the space to spare, you might want to consider prepopulating a `sqrt` table to get it out of the inner loop. It would speed it up, and if you've got the memory to spare, there's no real down side to it.

For a quick test, [here's an ideone.com example](http://ideone.com/FxvYDZ).

**Edit:** If you're looking for a sieve, this is fine. However, I must say that [jwpat7's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19386268/752320) is 1)faster, 2) constant space, and 3) more elegant (IMO). There's basically no reason to use a sieve unless you're interested in the mechanics of it.